# How to make a protected range in Google Sheet accessible for a javascript function from App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I shared a Google Sheets but protected certain range from editing. Now, I cannot edit the range programmatically from App Script, ex. set a value to a cell. Question: Is there a way to keep the range protection (prevent users from editing the protected range) and edit it via script? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I haven't found what you are trying to find, but I thought of a workaround that should work almost the same with what you are trying to do.

Try removing the range protection via script then modify the protected range and adding the protection again.

```
function main() {
  // Remove protection before editing
  removeProtectionToColumn();
  // Call your function that modifies the protected range in between
  modifySheetDataFunction(); 
  // Add protection again
  addProtectionToColumn();
}

function addProtectionToColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A:A');
  var protectSs = range.protect().setDescription('Protect column A');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protectSs.addEditor(me);
  protectSs.removeEditors(protectSs.getEditors());
  if (protectSs.canDomainEdit()) {
    protectSs.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}

function removeProtectionToColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    if (protections[i].getDescription() == 'Protect column A') {
      protections[i].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

There should be a very little window time here and should be feasible to whatever you are trying to work unless you are modifying a very very very big set of data. You can always test this behavior with your colleagues.

For more details regarding protection, please see this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I have a small problem. The function that hat modifies the protected range in between is called by pushing the button on a sidebar and it takes user form entries as parameter (array) and sets the same array on the protected range. So, it is written as modifySheetDataFunction(array); when I put the other two functions inside this function (modifySheetDataFunction(array)) and call them, nothing happens other than the array appears on unprotected range.  And, I cannot call function main by pressing the button and send the array as param. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: By default, the protection is applied only for other users, it won't affect the one adding it, in this case, you and the scripts you run can still edit the sheet manually even if the range is already protected. What you can do is try editing it in incognito using another user to see that the applied protection is working.